# What could couse my laptop to turn on (boot splash included) only after ~20-30 minutes?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, hardware-failure

I have a Dell laptop where I first installed Linux (ubuntu) and then, on a separate partition, Windows.

Now it starts Windows but after like 20 minutes or so.

When I press the on button it does just blink a moment the power icon and does nothing, not the Boot splash, not the CD-ROM check, nothing of nothing, so I thought that there was some hw problem, but after 20-30 minutes I can hear the windows sound and indeed moving the mouse.. I get the screen!
What could it be? Reinstalling Linux on the master boot record could solve the issue ?

[EDIT]
Solved (after lot of attempts..) by updating the BOOT firmware from Dell. But this experience changed a bit my assumptions on how pcs works.. the installation of Windows 10 didn't just happen at the level of post-firmware stuff, but went to change something at the PC firmware level.. a bit "scaring" for me...

Comment: Please clarify is it only Windows which boots wrong, or is it whole computer which doesn't boot properly.
In first case, repair of boot record does have a chance to mitigate problem.
In second, I would suspect some coincident hardware failure. Check with some LiveCD first.

Comment: @Aramil: it's really strange.. when I finally get Windows and I reboot, it is super fast. I did try to reinstall Linux, but differently than other times, it doesn't see Windows on the side, and if I try manually I see that Windows installation did a really strange partition table.. I don't "feel" it's an hardwar issue, but  more like windows did install itself more at the root than what was normally done in previous versions....